# How to handle request timeout exception?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 with C# 2008.

For some operation in my web application after updating database, I am calling a third-party service. Now, sometime it happens that it take more time to get the response from that service. So that firebug shows me "`The server request timed out.`" error and my page is not getting updated even if I have already committed my changes to database.

Can I handle this error?

One solution is to refresh the page on catching this exception. For this I have searched a lot but not get any server-side code.

I got some java-script block to handle the server error as below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(requestEndHandler );

// This function will handle the end request event
function requestEndHandler(sender, args) {
   if( args.get_error() ){
      document.getElementById("errorMessageLabel").innerText = 
         args.get_error().description;
      args.set_errorHandled(true);
   }
}

</script>
```

But how can I know that the error is Page Request time out error? And how to refresh the page if this exception caught?

Any other solution?

Thanks..

Comment: Please share code where you are calling a third-party service.

Comment: actually I am making a google push notification..